# How to cast the object from linq

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

```
var query = (from RESTAURANT in db.RESTAURANTs
             where RESTAURANT.REST_ID == RestID
             select new { name = RESTAURANT.name});
```

How to cast the `query` instead of `var`?

thank you.

Add more information, i want to make the following possible. Is it possible?

[image]

Comment: `select RESTAURANT.name` ?

Comment: I mean i don't want to use `var` in front of the query. I want to use the specific class.

Comment: You *must* use `var` in this case because you're projecting into anonymous type. `IEnumerable<object>` would not give you what you want. Alternatively, create a class for the result and use `IEnumerable<YourClass>`.

Comment: You can't, you're creating an anonymous type.

Comment: I add more information about what i'm expecting.

Comment: With the var keyword you have to assign it at creation.  Otherwise the compiler can't infer the actual type to use.

Comment: @theB That's what i ask. What should i assign `query` to.

Comment: See Yuval's answer below.  You can't use an anonymous type in your query in this case.  Also, if you are just looking for `RESTAURAUNT.name` it would be easier to just select the value and use its type for the IEnumerable

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your query currently allocates an anonymous type using `select new { }`, which requires you to use `var`. If you want allocate a known type, add it to your `select` clause:

```
IEnumerable<SomeType> query = 
         from RESTAURANT in db.RESTAURANTs
         where RESTAURANT.REST_ID == RestID
         select new SomeType { Name = RESTAURANT.name } ;

public class SomeType
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I would change "concrete type" to "known type". The generated anonymous type is still a concrete type.

Answer (score 1):

Mouse-over the `var` and your compiler will tell you what type it substitutes for it.

If you want to use that type explicitly instead, you will need to insert it instead of `var`. It won't change anything for the compiler though.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
var query = (from RESTAURANT in db.RESTAURANTs
             where RESTAURANT.REST_ID == RestID
             select new { name = RESTAURANT.name});
```

defines a *query*. When your program is running, and this line has been processed, the `query` variable refers to a query instance. The database has not yet been invoked.

If you append (for instance) `.ToList()` to your statement like this:

```
var query = (from RESTAURANT in db.RESTAURANTs
             where RESTAURANT.REST_ID == RestID
             select new { name = RESTAURANT.name}).ToList();
```

Then `query` will contain a list of items that were fetched from the database. But still in this case, the type of the items in the list is an anonymous type, so you still cannot change the `var` to a named type. If you want that then you need to have the query return a known named type. Like this:

```
List<string> query = (from RESTAURANT in db.RESTAURANTs
             where RESTAURANT.REST_ID == RestID
             select RESTAURANT.name).ToList();
```

or maybe like this:

```
public class Restaurant 
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
}

List<Restaurant> query = (from RESTAURANT in db.RESTAURANTs
             where RESTAURANT.REST_ID == RestID
             select new Restaurant() { Name = name }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to declare `query` separately, 
use [?:operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) `var query = <condition> ? <1st Linq query> : <2nd Linq query>` instead of `if-else`
you can do this like that:

```
var query =  string.IsNullOrEmpty(dealer_code) ?  
             (from RESTAURANT in db.RESTAURANTs
             where RESTAURANT.REST_ID == RestID
             select new { name = RESTAURANT.name}):
             (from u in db.RESTAURANTs
             where u.dealer_code == dealer_code
             select new { name = u.name});
```